# OpenCV: Detect if area is straight or curved

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am playing around with OpenCV to detect the yellow line in traffic images. I am able to find (mostly) find the wanted area using a hsv mask:

```
lower = np.array([20,100,100])
upper = np.array([30,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower, upper) 

result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
```

The result from the masking (in grayscale):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIrTc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy0M3.png

I want to check if the mask is a straight or curved line.

I have tried using canny detection, with hough lines and with contours, but I have not been able to accurately predict if it is curved using any of these methods.

What is the best method to check if the area is curved or straight?

**Edit 1:**

The road is not necessarily the same direction. It can also be straight, or even point the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the difference (bitwise XOR) between the this binary image and convex hull from this binary image. This will be an indicator of curvature.

Comment: Yes, that would be posible, if the road-orientation is always the same, but although both examples have roughtly the same direction (about y=x), the direction of the line can also be very different (for example straight ahead)

Comment: Convexity defects  does not depend on the orientation of the road.
See cv.convexityDefects function.